# Android Studio Recycle View got error in method onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-recyclerview

After I implemented the tutorial about Recycle View in Android Studio.

The File Adapter file that i used:

```
package com.emilhamep.ilham_hp.diamondmaterial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

public RecycleAdapter(Context context,List<Information> data){
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current=data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        icon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon);
    }
}
}
```

I got the error in method `onBindViewHoder`:

[image: Adapter]

Does anyone, had gotten similar error with me when implementing Recycle View before?

Comment: Please add code of your adapter class here. Also give full error logcat.

Comment: @PriyaSinghal please check the question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **NullPointerException** because `holder.title` is **null**.

Check your `custom_row.xml`, you need to have a `TextView` with `list_item` as *id* (`android:id="@+id/list_item"`).

Or, change `list_item` in `title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);` with the right *id* of the `TextView` if it already have one.